# Having some issues with keyframe backround animations in IE

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations, internet-explorer-11

I am having a few issues with keyframe background animations in IE. I am trying to get a few images to slide up into position from off the screen on page load. This code works great in Chrome, but shows no animation in IE.

Here's my code for the animation:

```
@keyframes slideUp {
    from { background-position: left 50em, right 50em, left 50em, right 50em; }
    to { background-position: left bottom, right bottom, left bottom, right bottom; }
}

.content00001.page_container{
    background-image: url('../images/content00001/Asset9.png'), url('../images/content00001/Asset10.png'), url('../images/content00001/Asset11.png'), url('../images/content00001/Asset12.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left bottom, right bottom, left bottom, right bottom;
    background-size: 22% 100%, 22% 100%, 22% 70%, 22% 70%;
    -webkit-animation: 1.2s ease 0s slideUp;
       -moz-animation: 1.2s ease 0s slideUp;
        -o--animation: 1.2s ease 0s slideUp;
            animation: 1.2s ease 0s slideUp;
}
```

Any help on what I'm missing here would be great!

Answer (score 0):

You might have to copy your keyframe and add a -webkit- prefix to it. You might also try changing "from" to "0%"

```
@-webkit-keyframes slideUp {
    0% { background-position: left 50em, right 50em, left 50em, right 50em; }
    to { background-position: left bottom, right bottom, left bottom, right bottom; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! but it still doesn't show up in IE... They just pop up on the page in IE and animate great in chrome. I'm at a loss here.. Maybe another animation or transform to try other than moving the background position?

Comment: What version of IE are you using? Another useful tip is to never use the transition and animation property together on the same element. I know that sounds odd but it causes issues in some browsers